# Install perl 5.20.3 fails on IO-Socket-IP/t/04local_client_v6.t

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, centos, ipv6

On installing perl 5.20.3I get the following error.

```
failed test: IO::Socket::IP-new constructs a SOCK_STREAM socket. line 55
```

On looking further I extracted the following code to demonstrate the problem.

https://gist.github.com/icydee/68a008e5b44544ce8b97e638bdd92526

On the linux (centos) system I am installing it on it fails (with timeout) on the IO::Socket::IP constructor.

On another linux system the code runs with no problem.

At this stage it seems to me to be a server configuration problem, but I am at a loss as to where to go next?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a firewall problem.

```
service ip6tables stop
```

was the solution.

Comment: Disabling your firewall is not the solution. A test failed. You realize it was a spurious failure due to the firewall instead of something being wrong with the module itself, so you go ahead and install it, ignoring the failure instead of disabling your protection.

Comment: That's what I did the first time (some weeks ago) and all that happened was that the IPV6 code  that I wrote did not work. So disabling the firewall would appear to fix those problems too.

Comment: In that case, find rule that is interfering with your application. Find out if your application is at fault, or if the rule really is not necessary. Then decide whether to correct your application or to make an exception in the firewall. Don't disable the entire firewall.

Comment: I am not interested in further discussion. As far as I am concerned, I've already warned you not to smoke around gasoline. The rest is your problem.